# Why cant I open a netcdf file

Tags: r, netcdf, netcdf4

I am trying to open a netcdf file in R, and I've seen people using a double \ or one /, but neither is working for me.

```
fn<- ("C:/Users/Madison-Riley/Desktop/Temperature")
ncfile<- nc_open("Temp_Q1_2020")
print(nc_file)
```

I copied the file path from directory so i dont see the problem?

Comment: Without knowing what specifically "is not working", i. e. without the error message, it's hard to tell (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Anyway, check whether file `Temp_Q1_2020` indeed has no file extension like ".nc", whether your work directory (`getwd()`) indeed contains said file, and whether you indeed want to print `nc_file`, not `ncfile`.

Comment: This is the following Error :        Error in R_nc4_open: No such file or directory
Error in nc_open("Temp_Q1(2020)") :
Error in nc_open trying to open file Temp_Q1(2020) (return_on_error= FALSE )

Comment: This is the revised code, yet I get the same error as above:                                                           
                                                                                                                                  
 fn<-("C://Users//Madison-Riley//Desktop//Thesis//Environmental_Data//Temperature")
ncfile<- nc_open("Temp_Q1(2020)")
print(ncfile)